# anti-logarithm (base $10$)

Tags: logarithms, approximation

Let's say that I start with the $\log_{10}7$, which is $0.84509804$, and I want to calculate $10^{0.84509804}$. $\ \ 0.84509804$ is close to $431/510$. Without access to anything electronic, it seems that I would have to find the $510^{th}$ root of $10^{431}$. I believe that would be an iterative process requiring calculating $X^{510}$ for each iteration. Is that how the table values were calculated prior to 1950? It seems unbelievably tedious.

I apologize for my lack of proper notation.

Comment: nice question. You're right that the iterative process would be way too slow. Our ancestors knew many tricks for approximating roots, which our computers are still using under the hood; for example, Newton's method.

Comment: Yes, Newton's method. It's been more than 30 years since I took Numerical Analysis, but I should have remembered that. Thanks.

Comment: There was a lot of tedium in calculating tables.  In years past "calculator" was a profession, not an electronic device.  It was a full time job.  There is a lot of regularity in tables which can relieve some of the work.  I don't know what approaches were used.  I can imagine that if you were going to do a table of base 10 logs, you might start with 1.1.  Having done that you could get 1.21 by doubling, 1.331 by tripling and other values with small corrections.  Then find the ones in between by interpolation.

Comment: Putting aside the interesting approximation questions, I should point out that $10^{\log_{10}7}=7$, exactly.

Comment: Apropos of **Ross Millikan**'s comment, the (often scientifically well-educated) people would did this sort of work from about the late 19th to mid-20th Centuries were called "computers" (the computers Feynman oversaw at Los Alamos were a roomful of people); a couple centuries earlier, they were known as _arithmetikers_.  This is why, during the late 1940s to 1960s, the enormous room-filling machines that took over such work were always referred to as "_electronic_ computers".

Comment: A few brief references:  https://fiziko.bureau42.com/teaching_tidbits/manual_logarithms.pdf

https://calipertimepieces.com/2017/12/calculating-logarithms-manually/

https://worldmentalcalculation.com/how-to-calculate-logarithms/   Working in base-10 is convenient because shifting the decimal place lets you use work you've already done; for instance, $ \ \log 1.6 \ = \ 4 · \log 2 \ - \ 1 \ \ , \ $ and so forth.